# Ruby HTTPClient: How to use persistent connections?

Tags: ruby, http, httpclient

How does one use persistent HTTP connections with HTTPClient? Is it just a matter of setting Keep Alive when sending a HTTP Request? The documentation states persistent connections are supported, but doesn't tell us how to use them.

Comment: I would guess it uses a persistent connection by default if the server speaks HTTP/1.1, since that's part of [the spec (RFC 2616)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html).  Do you believe otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the HttpClient [Readme](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient):

> you don't have to care HTTP/1.1 persistent connection
>       (httpclient cares instead of you)

That usually means that in the scenario  that the server supports `HTTP 1.1` persistent connections, the `httpclient gem` will store and re-use them (the connections) for subsequent requests. In which case, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will approve this as the answer... this may bea  silly question, but httpclient only reuse the connection if I reuse the httpclient instance right?

Comment: @HenleyChiu I would think so, yes.

Comment: I think that is a bad answer, specifically because if you have to reuse the httpclient instance then you do have to worry about it.

Answer (score 9):

It's [available in Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)

As written in the doc,

> `Net::HTTP.start` immediately creates a connection to an HTTP server which is kept open for the duration of the block. The connection will remain open for multiple requests in the block if the server indicates it supports persistent connections.

That means **all the request you'll do in the block will use the same HTTP connection.**

The example from the doc

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://google.com/')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```